# Data importer not recognizing table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a DataImporter class to import data from an old database, tweak it a bit and then inject it into a new database. See my code below, it nicely retrieves all old visits with line `Visit.all` from the database, but when it wants to retrieve all old clubs with line `Club.all` it returns the error: `uninitialized constant DataImporter::Club`

I know for sure that the `Club` model exists, so what is going wrong here?

```
class DataImporter
  require 'active_record'

  def import
    old_clubs = get_old_clubs
    old_leagues = get_old_leagues

    old_visits = get_old_visits
    old_visits.each do |old_visit|
      old_home_club = old_clubs.where(id: old_visit.club_id).first.name
      old_away_club = old_clubs.where(id: old_visit.club_away).first.name
      old_league = old_leagues.where(id: old_visit.league_visited).first.name

      create_new_visit(old_visit, old_home_club, old_away_club, old_league)
    end
  end

  private

  def set_connection(source)
    if source == "old"
      ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
        adapter:  "xxx",
        host:     "xxx",
        username: "xxx",
        port:     "xxx",
        password: "xxx",
        database: "xxx"
      )
    else
      ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
        adapter: "xxx",
        database: "xxx",
        pool: "xxx",
        timeout: "xxx"
      )
    end
  end

  def get_old_visits
    set_connection("old")
    Visit.all
  end

  def get_old_clubs
    set_connection("old")
    Club.all
  end

  def get_old_leagues
    set_connection("old")
    League.all
  end

  def create_new_visit(old_visit, old_home_club, old_away_club, old_league)
    set_connection("new")

    new_visit = Visit.new
    new_visit.visit_nr = old_visit.match_nr
    new_visit.the92_nr = old_visit.the92_nr
    new_visit.visit_date = old_visit.visit_date
    new_visit.ground = old_visit.ground
    new_visit.result = old_visit.result
    new_visit.season = old_visit.season
    new_visit.kickoff = old_visit.kickoff
    new_visit.gate = old_visit.gate
    new_visit.ticket_price = old_visit.ticket_price
    new_visit.countfor92 = old_visit.countfor92
    new_visit.longitude = old_visit.longitude
    new_visit.latitude = old_visit.latitude
    new_visit.gmaps = old_visit.gmaps
    new_visit.photo1 = old_visit.photo1
    new_visit.photo2 = old_visit.photo2
    new_visit.photo3 = old_visit.photo3
    new_visit.photo4 = old_visit.photo4
    new_visit.dropbox_programme = old_visit.dropbox_programme
    new_visit.dropbox_ticket = old_visit.dropbox_ticket
    new_visit.rating_match = old_visit.rating_match
    new_visit.rating_ground = old_visit.rating_ground
    new_visit.rating_atmosphere = old_visit.rating_atmosphere
    new_visit.rating_trip = old_visit.rating_trip
    new_visit.ticket = old_visit.ticket
    new_visit.programme = old_visit.programme
    new_visit.home_club = old_home_club
    new_visit.away_club = old_away_club
    new_visit.league = old_league

    address_parts = old_visit.address.split(", ")
    new_visit.street = address_parts[0]
    new_visit.city = address_parts[1]
    new_visit.country = address_parts[2]

    new_visit.save
    puts "MATCH ADDED: #{new_visit.home_club} v #{new_visit.away_club}"
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that model is required use this snippet

```
require 'pp'
pp $LOADED_FEATURES
```

If so, also try using root namespace by calling `Club` class using:

```
::Club.all
```

Good luck